# Swift Package Manger: Package with Sub-Packages

Tags: ios, swift, package, swift-package-manager

I'm fairly new to SPM and I'm trying to create a package that has local packages, but when I try to import this package from the SPM I receive this message:

```
package 'MyMainPackage' is required using a revision-based requirement and it depends on local package 'MySubPackage', which is not supported
```

This would be an example of the package structure:

```
MyMainPackage
|
--- MySubPackage
--- MyOtherSubPackage
--- MyLastSubPackage
```

If this really not supported?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your current `Package.swift`?